# Upserting Appropriate Fields Based On JSON Function Parameter

Tags: postgresql, upsert, postgresql-10

I have the following table, called `operator`, defined below in a v10 database. I want to upsert into this table based on a function with the following signature. The JSONB argument may or may not have any of the fields on the table. (Note that `username` or `primary_email` are not null and are alternate keys, so will (should) always be present in the JSON object and I use it for any more usual `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT operator_primaryemail_uidx` type upsert.) What are my options for doing this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_operator(_data JSONB DEFAULT NULL)

Example JSON: {
  "username": "potato",
  "last_name": "doe",
  "street": "123 Main St."
}

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS operator (
  id                  UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1mc(),

  party_id            UUID,

  username            VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  profile_picture_uri VARCHAR(512),
  first_name          VARCHAR(64),
  last_name           VARCHAR(64),
  street              VARCHAR(128),
  specifier           VARCHAR(128),
  city                VARCHAR(64),
  state               VARCHAR(2),
  zipcode             VARCHAR(9),
  primary_email       CITEXT NOT NULL,
  primary_phone       VARCHAR(10),
  secondary_email     CITEXT,
  secondary_phone     VARCHAR(10),
  is_locked           BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  must_reset_pwd      BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  retry_count         SMALLINT DEFAULT 0,
  signed_eula         BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  last_login          TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,

  created             TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT statement_timestamp(),
  updated             TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT 'infinity',
  deleted             TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT 'infinity',

  -- keys
  CONSTRAINT operator_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT operator_party_fk FOREIGN KEY (party_id)
      REFERENCES party(id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,

  -- checks
  CONSTRAINT operator_username_ak UNIQUE(username),
  CONSTRAINT operator_primaryemail_uidx UNIQUE(primary_email),
  CONSTRAINT operator_updated_gt_created CHECK (updated >= created),
  CONSTRAINT operator_deleted_gt_created CHECK (deleted >= created)
)
```

Comment: You  execute `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` just like you said. I guess I don't see what your problem is.

Comment: Say I pass the example JSON, I don't want an update that nulls say `first_name` because it's not in the argument. The next object may have a `first_name` but not a `last_name`. I was wondering if there's one or more ways to update  dynamically.

Comment: What about using the `coalesce` function in the `ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE` clause so that you reuse the original values if the new values are NULL?

Comment: Assume a statement `UPDATE operator SET first_name = _first_name...`, where `_first_name` is derived from `jsonb_populate_record(NULL::operator, _data)`, but `_data` doesn't have `first_name` as a property. What then? What if we want many of the properties to optionally exist in `_data`? I'm trying to understand how to handle this variability? What are some options? Hopefully, that clarifies my intent.

Comment: `... DO UPDATE SET first_name = coalesce(EXCLUDED.first_name, first_name) `